# Using $lookup and $group to aggregate data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am aggregating a large data where i need to group the data according to their types and also i need to lookup the data from another collections.inside $group i want my lookup's data.
my code for aggregation goes like :

```
NotificationSchema.aggregate([{
  $match: condition
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$type",
    details: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    _id: -1
  }
}, {

  $lookup: {
    from: "vehicles",
    localField: "details.device_id",
    foreignField: "device_id",
    as: "vehicle"
  }
}], function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500);
    return res.json({
      result: err
    });
  }
  console.log('res', result[0].details[0]);
  res.json({
    result: result
  });
});
```

if i remove or comment the $group code i get the data with Vehicle array  but using $group i get vehicle array empty, as i have only two types in records in the database, i get two empty array of vehicles. but i have 102 records so i need 102 arrays of vehicles how can i get such result.
what i am getting in console right now is

```
res [ { _id: 'Vehicle Delay Alert!',
    details: 
     [ [Object],
       ....57 object...
       [Object] ],
    count: 57,
    vehicle: [] },
```

and inside every object i dont find vehicle array so i wish to remove vehicle array from here and get a vehicle array that is generated from $lookup inside every object.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `$lookup` from `details.device_id` which comes from an array. To `$lookup` from a regular field, you can place `$lookup` after the `$match` :

```
NotificationSchema.aggregate([{
    $match: condition
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "vehicles",
        localField: "device_id",
        foreignField: "device_id",
        as: "vehicle"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$type",
        details: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        _id: -1
    }
}])
```

Comment: i owe you sir.  also i want to limit the record for only 50 but want to know the total length of the records.how can i perform this.without using $group now. :)

Comment: you can use $limit to limit the number of record : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/. If you dont want to count the number using $group you can get the length of the result

Comment: as i know i will get the data as per defined in the limit. i can get 50 records but want to get total records length also if total length is 19808 then i  want to fetch only 50 data and total length of 19808